# In django, how can I pass the output of ansible_runner to the page through websocket?

Tags: django, ansible

I want to display the output similar to the following on the page in real time, or save it to the database after being captured. I think ansible_runner should have such an interface, but I can't find it

```
Tuesday 30 May 2023  08:45:30 +0800 (0:00:00.059)       0:00:00.059 *********** 
12.212.212.22 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_memfree_mb": 258388,
        "ansible_memtotal_mb": 515659,
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false
}
Tuesday 30 May 2023  08:45:33 +0800 (0:00:02.731)       0:00:02.790 *********** 
=============================================================================== 
setup ------------------------------------------------------------------- 2.73s
```

Comment: JFYI. Ansible facts are collected on demand. See [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-gather_subset). Is this what you want 'in real time'?

Comment: See [Ansible CMDB](https://ansible-cmdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): *"Ansible-cmdb takes the output of Ansible's fact gathering and converts it into a static HTML overview page..."*.

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"I want to save the output to a database after being captured."***

A: *ansible-runner* creates persistent [artifacts](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy). Consider the *artifacts* a database you might want to parse. See the [example](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example2-events.html#playbook).